# No artifact Created during the CI in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create an Azure pipeline for a .NET core project. The build appears to complete with no errors but there is no artifact generated:
[Here you can the warnings as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W302n.jpg)

The YAML definition is below, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here
trigger:
branches:
include:
- release/*
paths:
include:
- Reeft/Organization/OrganizationService/*
- Reeft/Organization/OrganizationServicePipelines/organization-service-test.yml

```
            pool:
              vmImage: 'windows-2022'
            
            variables:
              solution: '**/*.sln'
              buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
              buildConfiguration: 'Release'
              projectName: '**/F11.Web.csproj'
              runtime: 'win-x64'
            
            steps:
            - task: UseDotNet@2
              displayName: 'Use .NET 5 SDK (preview)'
              inputs:
                packageType: 'sdk'
                version: '5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10'
                vsVersion: '16.8.0'
                includePreviewVersions: true
            
            - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
              inputs:
                command: 'restore'
                projects: '$(projectName)'
                feedsToUse: 'select'
            
            - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
              displayName: Build
              inputs:
                projects: '$(projectName)'
                arguments: '--no-restore'
            
            - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
              displayName: Test
              inputs:
                command: test
                projects: '$(projectName)'
                arguments: '-l "console;verbosity=detailed"'
            
            - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
              displayName: 'Publish WebApi'
              inputs:
                command: publish
                publishWebProjects: false
                projects: '$(projectName)'
                arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --runtime -r $(runtime)'
            
            - task: CopyFiles@2
              inputs:
                Contents: '**'
                TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: Hi Taqi, any update? I think Bartosz's answer should answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

To generate artifacts you need to add appropriate task [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops):

```yaml
# Publish build artifacts
# Publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines or a Windows file share
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    #pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    #artifactName: 'drop' 
    #publishLocation: 'Container' # Options: container, filePath
    #targetPath: # Required when publishLocation == FilePath
    #parallel: false # Optional
    #parallelCount: # Optional
    #fileCopyOptions: #Optional
    #storeAsTar: false # Optional
```